# Get the timestamp of exactly one week ago in PHP?

Tags: php, datetime, timestamp

I need to calculate the timestamp of exactly 7 days ago using PHP, so if it's currently March 25th at 7:30pm, it would return the timestamp for March 18th at 7:30pm.

Should I just subtract 604800 seconds from the current timestamp, or is there a better method?

Answer (score 88, accepted):

```
strtotime("-1 week")
```

Answer (score 27):

[strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) is your friend

```
echo strtotime("-1 week");
```

Comment: You have typo strotime for strtotime .. :) too early just 5 yrs ago .. .:D

Answer (score 11):

http://php.net/strtotime

```
echo strtotime("-1 week");
```

Answer (score 9):

There is the following example on [PHP.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.time.php)

```
<?php
  $nextWeek = time() + (7 * 24 * 60 * 60);
               // 7 days; 24 hours; 60 mins; 60secs
  echo 'Now:       '. date('Y-m-d') ."\n";
  echo 'Next Week: '. date('Y-m-d', $nextWeek) ."\n";
  // or using strtotime():
  echo 'Next Week: '. date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+1 week')) ."\n";
?>
```

Changing + to - on the first (or last) line will get what you want.

Answer (score 4):

From **PHP 5.2** you can use [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/pl/class.datetime.php):

```
$timestring="2015-03-25";
$datetime=new DateTime($timestring);
$datetime->modify('-7 day');
echo $datetime->format("Y-m-d"); //2015-03-18
```

Instead of creating `DateTime` with string, you can [setTimestamp](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimestamp.php) directly on object:

```
$timestamp=1427241600;//2015-03-25
$datetime=new DateTime();
$datetime->setTimestamp($timestamp);
$datetime->modify('-7 day');
echo $datetime->format("Y-m-d"); //2015-03-18
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
   $before_seven_day = $date_timestamp - (7 * 24 * 60 * 60)
   // $date_timestamp is the date from where you found to find out the timestamp.
?>
```

you can also use the string to time function for converting the date to timestamp. like

```
strtotime(23-09-2013);
```

Comment: @AndrewBarber The answer may have been edited, but this answer does not appear to include a link to anything.