# Create the timestamp of an hour ago

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to create a timestamp by a variable of hour.

for example:
current timestamp is:

```
2015-09-29 14:00:00
```

my variable is : `$hour = 2`

new timestamp that I want:

```
2015-09-29 16:00:00
```

Comment: `strtotime(-2 hours)` You said timestamp, not datetime.

Comment: Check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7811609/php-add-two-hours-to-date-variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `strtotime` function of php.

for example:

```
$twoHoursAgo = Date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("-2 hours"));
```

for more refer below link [Get the timestamp of exactly one week ago in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507678/get-the-timestamp-of-exactly-one-week-ago-in-php)

Comment: It returns nothing ! `$twoHoursAgo = new Date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("-2 hours"));

echo $twoHoursAgo ;`

Comment: @S.M_Emamian because you've used `= new Date(...` rather than `= date(...`